# How can I access the properties of a custom object in the App variable in webmatrix?

Tags: c#, dynamic, global-variables, webmatrix

I have this custom object with some info from my database:

```
App.Model = new
{
  Niveles = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)db.Query("select * from nivel"),
  Dificultades = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)db.Query("select * from dificultad"),
  Asignatura_Eje_Nivel = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)db.Query("select * from asignatura_eje_nivel"),
  Asignatura = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)db.Query("select * from asignatura")
};
```

I want to query this object using LINQ in this way:

```
var asignaturas = (from x in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)App.Model.Asignatura
                     from y in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)App.Model.Asignatura_Eje_Nivel
                    where y.id_nivel == nivel
                       && x.id_asignatura == y.id_asignatura
                    select x).Distinct();
```

The problem is that when I attempt to do that I get an exception telling me that Model (of type Object) doesn't contain a definition for Asignatura...and any of the other properties. In consequence I want to know, How can I access those objects correctly?